# Why is "expiryText" not working for countdown plugin?

Tags: jquery, parameters, countdown

I'm using Keith Wood's jQuery countdown plugin and have an issue.  It won't display the "expiryText" parameter I've set when the countdown reaches zero.  Below is the code I have implemented:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".counter").countdown({
        until: new Date(2014, 8-1, 20),
        description: ' Until Our Wedding!',
        format: "d",
        expiryText: "<div>Already Married!!!</div>"
    });
});
```

Since the date is set to August 20, 2014, it should display the "Already Married!!!", but it's not.  Rather, it's showing simply "Until Our Wedding!".  When I change it to a future date though, it works like a charm.

Any idea why this wouldn't be working?

Source: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: Answer found, see below:

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.  The `alwaysExpire` need to be set to `true` for the expire to trigger when the timer is started after the target date.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".counter").countdown({
        until: new Date(<?php echo $wedding_year.", ".$wedding_month."-1, ".$wedding_day; ?>),
        description: ' Until Our Wedding!',
        format: "d",
        alwaysExpire: true,
        expiryText: "Already Married!"
    });
});
```

Reference: http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#alwaysExpire